# Runtime of modular expansion

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I understand nearly everything about cryptology, but runtime and bit operations. I have following problem:

How many bit operations are necessary to calculate a^n mod m for constant m and a.

I have found a lot about this topic, but only for optimised algorithms and without explanations. Could somebody help?

Comment: did you see the square and multiply? Also, in this style, this question is too broad.

Comment: Yes I have seen it, but I just want to know how many bit operations it takes to calculate it by just straight up multiplication and division. No fancy faster algorithms, just the bruteforce.

Comment: What is a brute force here? Brute force is trying all possibilities. Do you mean the naive method? That is multiplying $a$ $n$-times than using the euclidean algorithm do find the remainder? Or, something else?

Comment: Yes exactly. I really don't know how to get from this knowledge to the number of bitoperations/runtime.

Comment: let say a is $k$-bit number then $a*a$ is $2k+1$-bit number....

Answer (score 0):

A single grade school multiply, takes at least $2y^2$ individual operations where $y$ is the length of the number in the base you are using. it usually produces a number with roughly twice as many bits roughly. This quadruples the square of $y$, so the total number of operations for raising to the $n$-th power is **very** roughly going to be: $$2\cdot{4^{n-1}-1\over 3}y^2$$ **EDIT**: forgot this is modular arithmetic, so it will take less in the sense that the length of the value is limited. Then you account for the fact that mod $m$ is mod $2^x$ and then add a certain value from above that point a certain number of times.